# How can I understand this definition of a presheaf?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors

We have given the following definition of a presheaf:

> A preasheaf $F$ on a topological space is a functor $$F:\text{Op}(X)^{\text{op}}\rightarrow \text{Sets}$$
> Where $\text{Op}$ is the category of open sets.

Now I want to understand this a bit more. So I know that a functor maps objets to objects, but since the objects in $\text{Op}(X)^{\text{op}}$ are the same as the one in $\text{Op}(X)$ we have

- for all $U\subset X$ open $F(U)$ is a set

Now a functor maps morphisms to morphisms. But the morphisms in $\text{Op}(X)^{\text{op}}$ are the one from $\text{Op}(X)$ but with arrows in the other direction right? But the morphisms in $\text{Op}(X)$ are inclusions of opens sets. But now if I have $V\subset U$ in $\text{Op}(X)$ then this means that $U\subset V$ in $\text{Op}(X)^{\text{op}}$, but now what does happen if we apply the functor $F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that for each open set U inside X, $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a set, and for two open sets $U \subset V$ we have a morphism of sets $\rho_{V,U} :\mathcal{F}(V) \to \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. $\rho_{U,U}=id_{\mathcal{F}(U)}$
2. For $W \subset V \subset U$, $\rho_{U,W}=\rho_{V,W} \circ \rho_{U,V}$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! So this is the equivalent definition for a presheaf?

Comment: Sorry I think this question now is related to your explenation. When I speak about $\rho_{V,U}(f)$ for $f$ in $F(V)$ what do I mean exaclty, what is $f$ in $F(V)$? and what is then $\rho_{V,U}(f)$?

Comment: @user123234 Yes, this is just unpacking your your definition. Another way of thinking about it is to treat it as a contravariant function from Op(X) to Sets. F(V) is a set so f inside F(V) is an element of it. $\rho_{V,U}(f)$ is an element of F(U).

Comment: But what is an element of $F(V)$ isn't $f$ a function?

Comment: There isn’t any universal description of $F(V)$, this depends on the specific presheaf you are working with. The definition says that it is a set (since you work with presheaves of sets), so your $f\in F(V)$ is an element of the set. And the maps $\rho_{V,U}$ are just morphisms of sets, i.e. ordinary maps. The standard examples of (pre)sheaves are some classes of functions (continuous, smooth, etc.) so in this case for example $F=C^\infty$ and $f\in C^\infty(V)$ would be a function $f:V\to \mathbb R$, but that applies only to that case.

Comment: @T.P. ah okey thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Generally  the category Op$(X)$ has morphisms $V\to U$ iff $V\subset U$.

So the opposite category Op$(X)^{\rm op}$'s morphism are $U\to V$ iff $V\subset U$.

Now we take functor $F:$Op$(X)^{\rm op}\to $Sets, we get map $F(U)\to F(V)$ when $V\subset U$.

For example let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $F(U):=\{f:U\to \mathbb{R}|f$:continuous } for open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, and by taking restriction of function there is $F(U)\to F(V)$ for $V\subset U$.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
But if a take a morphism in the opposite open category, $f:U\rightarrow V$ iff $V\subset U$ then what does $F(f)$ looks like, I don't get why we have $F(U)\rightarrow F(V)$

Comment: map $F(f)$ is one of definition of functor $F$.